# How to merge the empty header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

```
export const Columns = [
    {
        Header:"Id",
        // accessor:'id',
        columns:[
            {
                Header:'Id1',
                accessor:'id'
            },
            {
                Header:'Id2',
                // accessor:'id'
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        Header:"First Name",
        accessor:'first_name',
        colSpan:2
    },
    {
        Header:"Last Name",
        accessor:'last_name'
    },
    {
        Header:"Email",
        accessor:'email'
    },
    {
        Header:"Gender",
        accessor:'gender'
    }
]
```

This logic renders the table using react-table libary. I need to remove the empty header above the First Name, Last Name, Email and Gender. For reference I attached an image below [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3r8l.png).

I tried to render the data using react table and when I have a sub column for id, I got empty headers for rest of the columns now. In order to remove the empty headers what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

#### 1.) Make group without Header (unique id)

Create a new group with empty `header` and unique `accessor`.

```js
export const Columns = [
    {
        Header: "Id",
        columns: [
            {
                Header: 'Id1',
                accessor: 'id'
            },
            {
                Header: 'Id2',
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        Header: "", // empty header (if have got unique accessor)
        accessor: 'global-header', // important unique id for enable empty header
        columns: [
          {
              Header: "First Name",
              accessor: 'first_name',
              colSpan: 2
          },
          {
              Header: "Last Name",
              accessor: 'last_name'
          },
          {
              Header: "Email",
              accessor: 'email'
          },
          {
              Header: "Gender",
              accessor: 'gender'
          }
       ]
    }
]
```

#### 2.) Make group without Header (space)

Or you can set Header of group to space (as default):

```js
export const Columns = [
    {
        Header: "Id",
        columns: [
            {
                Header: 'Id1',
                accessor: 'id'
            },
            {
                Header: 'Id2',
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        Header: " ", // add space
        columns: [
          // ... - here your ungrouped columns
       ]
    }
]
```

#### 3.) With CSS

Or with css can you hide `border-right` when header generated by react and not declared by you:

```html
<th style={
  column.render('Header') instanceof Object ? { borderRight: 'none' } : {}
}>
  ...
</th>
```